# Normal data distribution as a constraint during data minimization using fmincon

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraints, normal-distribution, minimization

I want to solve a minimization problem between two datasets A and B defined here:

% sample data

```
nvars = 1000;
A = rand(69,1);
B = rand(69,nvars);
```

% Objective function

```
fun_Obj = @(Alpha,A,B) norm(A- sum(Alpha.*B(:,:),2),2);
```

I would like to introduce two constraints (**confuneq1** and **confuneq2**) during the data minimization of the objective function fun_Obj (between A and B), with **Alpha** as a variable parameter. Fmincon is defined as follow:

```
[~]=  fmincon(@(Alpha)fun_Obj(Alpha,A,B),x0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,{confuneq1;confuneq2},options);
```

with:

```
 - confuneq1 = @(Alpha)deal(-1, sum(Alpha)-1); % 1st constraint 
 - x0 = ones(1,nvars)/nvars; % starting values 
 - lb = zeros(1,nvars); ub = ones(1,nvars); % lower and upper bounds
```

The first constraint is working well. Regarding the second one, I want to force the module of **Alpha** to decrease when its index is increasing following a defined distribution (linear, normal...).

I tried to define several expression such as :

```
 - confuneq2 = @(Alpha)deal(-1,Alpha(i+1)<Alpha(i));
 - confuneq2 = @(Alpha)deal(-1,normpdf(Alpha,lb,sigma)-1) % Normal distribution decrease
```

but I can't manage to implement it correctly for fmincon.

Thanks a lot for your precious help.

Comment: What does not working means? Error message? Wrong result?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, and sorry for the delay of my anwer I mulled over to understand what was the problem. The first expression with the index number obviously doesn't work seems i is not recognized as the index number but as the imaginary number. Indeed, for the second expression of confuneq2 the result is wrong (even if the constraint at the end of the iterations are respected). I don't know how to introduce the fact that Alpha should decrease with the index ? Any idea ? Thx a lot.

Comment: You could try `all(diff(Alpha)<0)-1` , i'm not sure if this will give a good result tough.

Comment: You should create one row for each constraint. It may be easier to use a non inline/anonymous function for it. Using the matlab debugger to inspect the returned constraint may be useful to understand the problem better.